# can i call xslt function inside another function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

can i call a xsl function inside a function? I just want to compare the previous value and current value. for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//row[(position()-1)]/MONTH_ID" />
```

but, the code below is ok:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(position())-1" />
```

Comment: this code is ok: <xsl:value-of select="number(position())-1" />

Comment: Are you actually trying to find out the value of the **MONTH_ID** element from the previous **row** element? It would probably help if you showed a sample of the XML, and the result you are trying to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is yes, but I don't think you are asking the right question. You haven't said what you are trying to do, but your code sample doesn't do anything useful.

```
//row[(position()-1)]/MONTH_ID
```

When a number N is used in a predicate, it means `[position()=N]`, so your predicate means `[position() = position() - 1]`, which will always be false.

I think you are forgetting that the result of `position()` is sensitive to context, and the context inside a predicate is not the same as the context outside. The answer is to bind a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="//row[$p - 1]/MONTH_ID"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can nest XPath function. Below you can find an example:

```
substring(child::randlist/item[position()=1], 1, 10)
```

function position is called inside substring function.

Can you be more specific with comparison request?